# Loading Json file into bing map API with js

Tags: javascript, json, bing-maps

I'm working on a project where I have a json file that contains a list of companies, their phone numbers, addresses, etc. Currently I have it loading a list into a table with no real order. It works to list the companies, and displays their location on a map with a pin. I have it limited to display on 10 as its almost 5000 entries - at least until I get a sort/search function working. The issue I'm having is that the only way I can get the map to load and the pins to work is if I include them as part of the $.getJSON. If I create functions to load outside of this, I'm unable to call the information out of the JSON any longer, but likewise am not able to include the functions inside as they don't work. 
Here is the code I'm working with:

```
$.getJSON('MapDatabroke.json', function (data) {
    var output = "<table class = sample>";
    tableHeadings = "<thead>" +
        "<tr>" +
        "<th></th>" +
        "<th><u>Name:</u></th>" +
        "<th><u>Address:</u></th>" +
        "<th><u>City:</u></th>" +
        "<th><u>State:</u></th>" +
        "<th><u>Phone Number:</u></th>" +
        "<th><u>PO:</u></th>" +
        "<th><u>Towing:</u></th>" +
        "<th><u>Tires:</u></th>" +
        "<th><u>MC:</u></th>" +
        "<th><u>RoadSvc:</u></th>" +
        "<th><u>Notes:</u></th>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "</thead>";
    output += tableHeadings;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        var lat = data[i]["Lat"];
        var lon = data[i]["Lon"];
        var dist = 41.5;


        if (lat < dist) {
            output += "<tr>";
            if (data[i]["Website"] == '---') {
                output += "<td>" + ' ' + "</td>";
            } else {
                output += "<td><a href=\"" + data[i]["Website"] + "\">W</a></td>";
            }
            output += "<td>" + i + data[i]["Business Name"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i]["Address"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i]["City"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i]["StateListing"] + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i]["Phone"] + "</td>";
            if (data[i]["PO"] == 'FALSE') {
                output += "<td>" + data[i]["Notes"] + "</td>";
                output += "</tr>";
            }
        }

        output += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;

    });

function GetMap() {
    var map = null;
    var pinInfobox = null;
    // Initialize the map
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {
        credentials: "AqtpRoPv2sfmrgf9VhyvDV8hCOVGPJi0-9heYhxmB-WU24OzpTIOIR0-C4fD0jc-",
        center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45.5, -122.5),
        zoom: 7
    });

    // Creates a collection to store multiple pins
    var pins = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();

    // Create Pins
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        //pushpin location
        var position = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(data[i]["Lat"], data[i]["Lon"]);
        //Create the pin
        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(position);
        //add pin to collection
        pins.push(pin);
    }
    //add pins
    map.entities.push(pins);


    //create the info box
    pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(pin.getLocation(), {
        title: 'My Pushpin',
        description: 'It works!',
        visible: false,
        offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 15)
    });

    //add click event
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayInfobox);

    //hide box on map move
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'viewchange', hideInfobox);
}

function displayInfobox(e) {
    pinInfobox.setOptions({
        visible: true
    });
}

function hideInfobox(e) {
    pinInfobox.setOptions({
        visible: false
    });
}
```

The way it shows above, doesn't work. It will load the map, but will not load the information as well as give me a error of data not defined w/in the create pin. Any ideas how to assign the information so that way I can use it in functions later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try asigning a variable to the $.getJSON (var JSONData = $.getJSON...). In that way you can have the data outside the query.

On the other hand, you could also use $.ajax to do the query. It's just another way of doing things, a little more "tweakable". This example have some error handlers that will help you identify the problem.

Something like this:

```
var JSONdata = $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "MapDatabroke.json",
    cache : false,
    dataType: "json",               // Use when retrieving

    success: function(data) {
        // do something here after retrieving the "data".
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
        //Add these parameters to display the required response
        console.log( 'xhr.status: ' + xhr.status );
        console.log( 'thrownError: ' + thrownError );
    }
});
```

Also, check your json data (http://jsonlint.com/). Sometimes there is a comma where should not, or a missing bracket.

Comment: I'll have to try the ajax way. Adding additional functions w/in the function(data) { wont cause it to break? That is the issue I'm having, functions w/in functions not working.

Comment: The advantage of using the "success" paramenter, is that the callback function will execute AFTER the data is retrieved. It's the equivalent of using .done().
And using var JSONdata allows you to "catch" the data in JSONdata.data. It works the same when using $.getJSON(). In that way, you can send the data as variable and use it in another function.